# Импорт списка объектов из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть подмодуль:

```
.\ 
  ..\__init__.py
  ..\smth.py
```

Код `smth.py` такой:

```py
_all_ = ['A']
__all__ = _all_ + ['B']

class A:
    ''' Видимый в __init__ '''

class B:
   ''' Видимый только при импорте из этого файла '''

class C:
    ''' Доступен только по прямому импорту '''
```

Я не хочу захламлять пространство имён подмодуля, поэтому в `__init__` сделал так:

```py
from .smth import _all_ as _smth_all_
from .smth import *

__all__ = _smth_all_
```

Проблема в том, что `from .smth import *` импортирует всё, что будет в `smth.__all__`, то есть `smth.A` и `smth.B`, а мне нужен только `A`.

Писать же что-то типа `from .smth import A` я не хочу, тк имён много, а при добавлении новых придётся менять И `smth.py`, И `__init__.py`.

Есть решение, как импортировать из `smth.py` только те имена, которые находятся в `_all_`?

Comment: Ненужные для экспорта классы можно обьявить приватными. ` class __B:` тогда `from .smth import *` эти имена не увидит.

Comment: @Chorkov нет, не то. Список `__all__` в файле и нужент, чтобы `from .smth import *` импортировал только те имена, которые в нём указаны. Я же хочу сделать возможность импорта из файла `A` и `B`, но из файла `__init__` возможность импортировать только `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, у этого вопроса есть два ответа.

1, с молотком вместо микроскопа:

YAGNI. Пусть в файле `__init__.py` импортируются все и `A`, и `B`, но и что, пространство имён импорта будет всё равно формироваться из `__init__.__all__`, то есть `from __init__ import *` импортирует только `A`. Собственно, для этого `__all__` и нужен.

2, если всё-таки необходим микроскоп:

```py
# __init__.py
from .smth import _all_ as _smth_all_
smth = __import__('.smth', fromlist=_smth_all_)
globals().update({name: getattr(smth, name) for name in _smth_all_})
__all__ = _smth_all_
```